# IntelliJ 12.0.3 Ctrl-Alt-U no longer works?

Tags: intellij-idea

I only just discovered that show UML Diagrams no longer works in IntelliJ 12.0.3.

Does anyone know whether there is a problem with it? Or whether it has been intentionally removed?

ps: It still works fine in 11.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> works in 12.0.3 Ultimate Edition, and not in the Community edition.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and experienced the same as you.

The feature is disabled, and must be enabled by checking **"UML Support"** under **File**->**Settings**->**Plugins**